# How to debug an application requiring low ports to be opened with GDB on Ubuntu

Tags: debugging, gdb, port

I have an application that requires to open port `80`.

In accordance to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443#892391), I gave the binary capabilities to open low ports.
Also I gave capabilities to `gdb` itself.

When I run the binary, port is opened successfully, but when I run it with GDB I have error with `errno = 13`.

**IMPORTANT**: Running application with `sudo` is exactly the thing that I want to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I gave the binary capabilities to open low ports.

When the binary is being debugged (ptraced), the kernel ignores its capabilities. That is a reasonable security precaution, because a `ptrace`d binary can be made to do *anything*.

> Also I gave capabilities to gdb itself.

That doesn't change above picture.

> Running application with sudo is exactly the thing that I want to avoid

You don't have to run the application with `sudo`, just the GDB.

Alternatively, have the application open port 8080, and set up [port forwarding](https://askubuntu.com/a/579540).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to moot an alternative way of debugging your application using `authbind`.
This could help out in situations where the port number cannot / should not be changed in your application's code.

Using the information from [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/889122/how-to-get-tomcat-9-to-work-with-authbind-to-bind-to-port-80) article I did the following (one time process):

1. install `authbind` if needed
2. sudo touch `/etc/authbind/byport/80`
3. sudo chmod 500 `/etc/authbind/byport/80`
4. sudo chown *userid*.*userid* `/etc/authbind/byport/80`

(where "userid" reads the launching user, most likely your own)

From there on launch your application using:
`authbind --deep /path/to/app`

**Upside**: no need to change your port number in the code.
**Downside**: because your app needs to be started by `authbind` you may need to *attach* the debugger to the process, rather than debug straight from your favourite IDE.

There is no need to set the capabilities of your app (`setcap`) using this method.